# How can I make a hover overlay in HTML+CSS that both fits over the content and lets it expand?

Tags: html, css, hover, width

I'm trying to make a general purpose hover overlay that visually indicates when a user mouses over something.

Just a note, I highly recommend running all the inline code snippets to make it easier to understand what I'm trying to achieve!

#### Original issue

The following snippet is what I started out with. It works for most of my use cases, but when there's a lone element, the overlay is too wide.

```css
.buttonized-hover-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 100 !important;
}
```

```html
<h2>
this is how it was before. when i hover, the hovered overlay is too wide
</h2>
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div class="buttonized-hover-overlay"
       style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0.4, 0.48, 0.71, 0.6);">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <button>
    asdf
  </button>
</div>
```

#### Attempted solution

I then solved this by adding a `max-width: fit-content` (which works in Chrome, I need `-moz-fit-content` for Firefox) over the parent div:

```css
.buttonized-hover-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 100 !important;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  so i added a fit-content to the parent div. now the hovered part fits what's inside.
</h2>
<div style="position: relative; max-width: fit-content;">
  <div class="buttonized-hover-overlay" style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0.4, 0.48, 0.71, 0.6);">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <button>
    asdf
  </button>
</div>
```

#### This mostly works, but... what if I want the button to take up the full width?

Sometimes, what I really want is the inner content to take up all the available width. I'm going to revert the `max-width: fit-content;` in the parent for just a moment, and show how I would like the inner content to look in some cases:

```css
.buttonized-hover-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 100 !important;
}
```

```html
<h2>
     if we remove the <code>max-width: fit-content;</code> from the parent, the inner content can fill up the available horizontal space. THIS IS WHAT I WANT. but as you can see from the example below, reapplying will <code>max-width: fit-content;</code> (or `display: inline-block`) prevent the button from taking up all the available space.
    </h2>
    <div style="position: relative;">
      <div class="buttonized-hover-overlay"
           style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0.4, 0.48, 0.71, 0.6);">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <button style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
        asdf
      </button>
  </div>
```

#### So here's the problem. If I leave the `max-width: fit-content` on the parent div, I can't get the child div to take up the remaining space, no matter what I try.

```css
.buttonized-hover-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 100 !important;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  tried setting both the width and max-width of the child, but it is still getting constrained by the <code>max-width: fit-content;</code> on the parent, for some reason
</h2>
<div style="position: relative; max-width: fit-content;">
  <div class="buttonized-hover-overlay" style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; background-color: rgba(0.4, 0.48, 0.71, 0.6);">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <button style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
      asdf
  </button>
</div>
```

I tried setting both the `width` and `max-width` of the child to `100%`, but for some reason, these won't take up all the available horizontal space. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do? The only way I can say it succinctly is:

> How can I make a hover overlay in HTML+CSS that both fits over the content and lets it expand?

Open to having the hover effect work in a different way. I can't just set the background color, because it has to work with any element, including images, and elements that may have one or many background colors.

**Edit**: Add a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3y51so9L/1/) for anyone who wants to play with it.

Comment: why not considering pseudo element? or the use of `inline-block` instead of `fit-content`?

Comment: I considered the psuedo element approach, but I'm not able to get it to work. I'm not sure the result would be any different. This markup is programmatically generated, so I don't mind generating this.

Using `inline-block` seems to have the same result as `fit-content`. Can't get the inner div to expand to the whole line. `inline-block` is probably a better option, I just didn't know about it 

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```css
.buttonized-hover-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 100 !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;     display: inline-block;">
  <div class="buttonized-hover-overlay" 
  style="opacity: 0; 
  top: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px; 
  right: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  position: absolute; 
  background-color: rgba(0.4, 0.48, 0.71, 0.6);">
  </div>
  <button>
      long content in button
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't get the button to expand to take up all the remaining width, though.